# Laravel : auth()->user() returns null after manual login

Tags: php, json, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to manually login user from a  custom Json

In **UserController@manual_login**

```
$user = [
   'id' => '123456',
   'name' => 'name1',
   'email' => 'name1@gmail.com',
   'phone' => 123456789,
];
$user = new User((array) json_decode(json_encode($user)));
Auth::login($user);
info(auth()->user()); //  {"id":123456,"name":"name1","email":"name1@gmail.com","phone":123456789}
```

in next request wether in middleware, controller or blade view

```
info(auth()->check()); // false
info(auth()->guest()); // true
```

I've edited **Kernel.php** as below

```
protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticatesRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
];
```

Tested on both laravel 7 and 8

How can i make the manual login last for the session ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass a `true` flag to the login method.

```
Auth::login($user,true);
```

based on the [document](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.html#method_login), the default value for remember is `false`

Comment: this will try to insert the row in database. I don't have a dedicated table since my users comes from external json

Comment: so I think the only way left is to manually create a session inside your controller.

Comment: is there a way to manually create a session that'd give you Auth::check as true ? if yes then what name and value ?